# nvidia 1080 Ti on Ubuntu 16.04 very loud fans

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I asked this initially at SO, but was directed here.

I have a machine with an Asus Strix 1080 Ti card. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04. Sometimes randomly, the fans on the GPU start spinning up, very loudly, and they never stop. When the fans start, they just keep on running. The output from `nvidia-smi` is:

```
Tue Apr  3 15:35:39 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.48                 Driver Version: 390.48                        |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P8    14W / 275W |    224MiB / 11175MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1054      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           196MiB |
|    0      1935      G   compiz                                        25MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

No matter whether the fans are turning or not, the `Fan` is always at 0%. I have tried using `nvidia-xconfig` by setting coolBits to 4, so I can manually change the fan speed using the Nvidia X Server Settings. When I set it to something other then 0% the fans go crazy and don't stop, no matter how I change it. I've even put it back to the hardware defaults, and the fans still don't stop. I can see the change I make in `nvidia-smi`, but the fans just continue... This is only annoying because the fans are rather loud, otherwise I don't care.

Anyone else that has run into this or has a potential solution?

Answer (score 0):

So I had tried several things. Finally I just opened up the box and it seemed like only one fan of three was running crazy like this. Then I noticed that the card had been installed in the second PCI slot. I moved it to the top one, and then all the issues magically disappeared. I guess this is an issue with the drivers, or how X manages the card.